# Jackson - How to process (deserialize) nested JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

```
{
  vendors: [
    {
      vendor: {
        id: 367,
        name: "Kuhn-Pollich",
        company_id: 1,
      }
    },
    {
      vendor: {
        id: 374,
        name: "Sawayn-Hermann",
        company_id: 1,
      }
  }]
}
```

I have a Vendor object that can properly be deserialized from a single "vendor" json, but I want to deserialize this into  a `Vendor[]`, I just can't figure out how to make Jackson cooperate.  Any tips?

Comment: This is invalid JSON. `vendors` has as value an array, which has a single object, and the single object has a 'vendor' property, which is followed by a bare top-level opject. i.e. the second `vendor` object has no associated property in the single object that is in the array. Furthermore, the property names aren't strings, they need to be quoted in JSON. I'm guessing that you've typed the JSON in wrong? A good answer will depend on knowing what kind of JSOn you're actually working with.

Comment: Sorry, let me correct the JSON -- Should be fixed now

Comment: You're not able (or don't want) to have a Vendors class that contains a List<Vendor>?

Comment: I am but the issue is the fact that the Vendor object is a nested as the "vendor" property of each object in the array, rather than being the object itself.  This means I'd have to have a Vendors class with a list of VendorWrapper, where each VendorWrapper contains a single Vendor.  I have this setup now, but it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your data is problematic in that you have inner *wrapper* objects in your array. Presumably your `Vendor` object is designed to handle `id`, `name`, `company_id`, but each of those multiple objects are also wrapped in an object with a single property `vendor`.

I'm assuming that you're using the Jackson [*Data Binding*](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example) model.

If so then there are two things to consider:

The first is using a special Jackson config property. Jackson - since 1.9 I believe, this may not be available if you're using an old version of Jackson - provides [`UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE). It's designed for cases where your results are wrapped in a top-level single-property object that you want to discard.

So, play around with:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

The second is using wrapper objects. Even after discarding the outer wrapper object you still have the problem of your `Vendor` objects being wrapped in a single-property object. Use a wrapper to get around this:

```
class VendorWrapper
{
    Vendor vendor;

    // gettors, settors for vendor if you need them
}
```

Similarly, instead of using `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUES`, you could also define a wrapper class to handle the outer object. Assuming that you have correct `Vendor`, `VendorWrapper` object, you can define:

```
class VendorsWrapper
{
    List<VendorWrapper> vendors = new ArrayList<VendorWrapper>();

    // gettors, settors for vendors if you need them
}

// in your deserialization code:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, VendorsWrapper.class);
```

The object tree for VendorsWrapper is analogous to your JSON:

```
VendorsWrapper:
    vendors:
    [
        VendorWrapper
            vendor: Vendor,
        VendorWrapper:
            vendor: Vendor,
        ...
    ]
```

Finally, you might use the Jackson [*Tree Model*](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) to parse this into `JsonNodes`, discarding the outer node, and for each `JsonNode` in the `ArrayNode`, calling:

```
mapper.readValue(node.get("vendor").getTextValue(), Vendor.class);
```

That might result in less code, but it seems no less clumsy than using two wrappers.

Comment: Thank you, this is how I was doing it I just hoped there was a better way.   I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'd also like to see a solution using something like UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUES, only 1 level deeper, but I don't think it's possible. Another option of course is to use a custom deserializer, and just add hooks to look for the actual objects you're interested in and discard everything else, or to use the Jackson _Tree Model_ approach, throw away the top-level `JsonNode`, and take the JsonNodes that wrap your Vendors, call `getTextValue`, and pass _that_ to `mapper.readValue`. Jackson really gives you a surfeit of options.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a rough but more declarative solution.  I haven't been able to get it down to a single annotation, but this seems to work well.  Also not sure about performance on large data sets.

Given this JSON:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "wrapper": {
                "name": "Jack"
            }
        },
        {
            "wrapper": {
                "name": "Jane"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And these model objects:

```
public class RootObject {
    @JsonProperty("list")
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = SkipWrapperObjectDeserializer.class)
    @SkipWrapperObject("wrapper")
    public InnerObject[] innerObjects;
}
```

and

```
public class InnerObject {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
}
```

Where the Jackson voodoo is implemented like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface SkipWrapperObject {
    String value();
}
```

and

```
public class SkipWrapperObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements
        ContextualDeserializer {
    private Class<?> wrappedType;
    private String wrapperKey;

    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt,
            BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        SkipWrapperObject skipWrapperObject = property
                .getAnnotation(SkipWrapperObject.class);
        wrapperKey = skipWrapperObject.value();
        JavaType collectionType = property.getType();
        JavaType collectedType = collectionType.containedType(0);
        wrappedType = collectedType.getRawClass();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.readTree(parser);
        JsonNode wrapped = objectNode.get(wrapperKey);
        Object mapped = mapIntoObject(wrapped);
        return mapped;
    }

    private Object mapIntoObject(JsonNode node) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        JsonParser parser = node.traverse();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(parser, wrappedType);
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone!

Comment: +1 for `mapIntoObject(JsonNode)`... so if you want to use `readValue` with a `JsonNode` just pass its `traverse()`

Comment: Works well: one minor simplification I'd suggest is `ObjectMapper.convertValue()`, which can be used to replace 3 lines in `mapIntoObject`: `return mapper.convertValue(node, wrappedType);`

Comment: @Patrick, I tried running this example code. getting NPE in SkipWrapperObjectDeserializer at 
wrappedType = collectedType.getRawClass();
in createContextual() method. Can you please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

@Patrick
I would improve your solution a bit

```java
@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {        
    ObjectNode objectNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
    JsonNode wrapped = objectNode.get(wrapperKey);
    JsonParser parser = node.traverse();
    parser.setCodec(jp.getCodec());
    Vendor mapped = parser.readValueAs(Vendor.class);
    return mapped;
}
```

It works faster :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the party, but one approach is to use a static inner class to unwrap values:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class Scratch {
    private final String aString;
    private final String bString;
    private final String cString;
    private final static String jsonString;

    static {
        jsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"wrap\" : {\n" +
                "    \"A\": \"foo\",\n" +
                "    \"B\": \"bar\",\n" +
                "    \"C\": \"baz\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
    }

    @JsonCreator
    Scratch(@JsonProperty("A") String aString,
            @JsonProperty("B") String bString,
            @JsonProperty("C") String cString) {
        this.aString = aString;
        this.bString = bString;
        this.cString = cString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Scratch{" +
                "aString='" + aString + '\'' +
                ", bString='" + bString + '\'' +
                ", cString='" + cString + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static class JsonDeserializer {
        private final Scratch scratch;

        @JsonCreator
        public JsonDeserializer(@JsonProperty("wrap") Scratch scratch) {
            this.scratch = scratch;
        }

        public Scratch getScratch() {
            return scratch;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Scratch scratch = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Scratch.JsonDeserializer.class).getScratch();
        System.out.println(scratch.toString());
    }
}
```

However, it's probably easier to use `objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);` in conjunction with `@JsonRootName("aName")`, [as pointed out by pb2q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748184)