# Unable to deserialize JSON into a POJO (using Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using `Jackson` to deserialize the following `JSON` into a POJO:

```
{
    "etag": "\"SomeETag\"",
    "jobComplete": true,
    "jobReference": {
        "jobId": "someJobId",
        "projectId": "someProjectId"
    },
    "rows": [
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": "101"
                },
                {
                    "v": "FirstService"
                },
                {
                    "v": "firstAPI"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "f": [
                {
                    "v": "102"
                },
                {
                    "v": "SecondService"
                },
                {
                    "v": "SecondAPI"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalRows": "2"
}
```

Here's the POJO I'm using:

```
    @JsonAutoDetect
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Response {

        public String etag;
        public boolean jobComplete;
        public List<FWrapper> rows = new ArrayList<FWrapper>();
    }

    class FWrapper {
        public F f; 
    }

    class F {
        public List<VWrapper> vWrappers = new ArrayList<VWrapper>();       
    }

    class VWrapper {
        public String v;
    }
```

I'm using this piece of code to do the mapping:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Response response = mapper.readValue(response, Response.class);
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

> `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException`: Can not deserialize instance of mypackage.F out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@11563ff; line: 1, column: 227] (through reference chain: mypackage.Response["rows"]->mypackage.FWrapper["f"])

I checked several old questions with similar error, but couldn't resolve mine yet.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json)
one looks very similar to mine as the correct response says `Your data is problematic in that you have inner wrapper objects in your array`, which I think is the case with my data as well. But still I've not been able to do the correct POJO mapping. Any pointers will be appreciated.

EDIT: Corrected a typo (`Json` I'm using is valid)

Comment: One suggestion: try populating a `Response` instance, letting Jackson serialize it. See how that differs structurally from JSON input you get. That should explain the specific issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your class model doesn't match your JSON.

In your JSON, f is an array not an object. In your class F is an object which contains a list of stuff.

A mapping like this should work (untested)

```
public class Response {

    public String etag;
    public boolean jobComplete;
    public List<F> rows;
}


public class F {
    public List<V> f;
}

public Class V {
    public String v;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right. The wrappers are odd - they do not match the JSON object structure. +1.

Comment: Your point that `f` is not an object in the `JSON` is right! I removed F, kept FWrapper and VWrapper as they were before. `class FWrapper { public List<VWrapper> f; }` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your "rows" array doesn't have a closing square bracket **]**.

It makes the JSON invalid.

Read the error message carefully:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of mypackage.F **out of START_ARRAY token** at [Source: java.io.StringReader@11563ff; line: 1, column: 227] (through reference chain: mypackage.Response[**"rows"**]->mypackage.FWrapper["f"])

---

Now I see you modified the JSON - added it.

Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but that's just a typo in the question I posted. Original `Json` I'm using is valid, so this is not the issue.

Comment: @Swapnil Did you try to rerun it? The same issue?

Comment: As I said, the typo was only in the question I posted here. Original Json had that square bracket already. So yes, issue is still there.