# Jackson JSON mapping array to java class

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I want to map the following JSON:

```
[
  {
     "rate": {
        "id": "1",
        "value": "1"
     }
  },
  {
     "rate": {
        "id": "2",
        "value": "2"
     } 
  }
]
```

To `List<Rate>` using annotations. How can I map the `"rate"` property to the `Rate` object?

Would it not be possible to annotate it like this?

```
@JsonClassMapping("rate") // Fictitious annotation
public class Rate {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    int id;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    int value;
}
```

Thse JSON is slightly different from the supposed duplicate in [Jackson - How to process (deserialize) nested JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json). I cannot get the suggested solutions to work in my case.

Comment: Is your specific issue that the elements in the JSON array are single-property objects, and you want the `rate` property of those objects unwrapped into a `Rate` object to go directly into your `List`?

Comment: I think I have a duplicate, and this is going to dupe-hammer your question. Please ping me and flag for reopen if this doesn't address your issue.

Comment: The possible duplicate contains slightly different JSON, with a root attribute. I cannot get solutions suggested there to work for me. So please reopen my question.

Comment: Please explain the difference. Specifically, the need for a wrapper indirection (or manual parsing) appears identical.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work using the wrapper pattern, chopping the wrapper out after deserialization. So yes: the supposed duplicate put on a workable track. I still do not get however why there is not an option to simply map a class name to a json attribute.

Comment: It's unclear what that sort of setup would look like. If you can clearly articulate the syntax and semantics, then it seems like it might be a useful feature, and I'd suggest raising an issue against Jackson.

Comment: I edited the question. Does that clear things up?

Comment: That's not comprehensive enough for a library inclusion. The problem is that Jackson can't go looking for all possible classes that might have a wrapper annotation on them when it tries to deserialize.

Comment: I guess I am going have to take your word on that.

Answer (score 0):

have you try somthing like this?
List myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference>(){});