# Spring RequestBody needs to load nested Object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get an Object param to load in one of my classes but unable to get it to work. The outer object `DeviceInfo` loads up as expected but the `MobileDeviceData` does not due to it's being inside a `Transaction` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfoList, @RequestHeader(value=IN_AUTH_CUSTOMER_GUID) String inAuthIdentity) {
    ... code here ...
```

}

For clarity, here is my simplified @Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class DeviceInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private MobileDeviceReasonCode reasonCode;

    @JsonProperty("mobile-data")
    private MobileDeviceData mobileDeviceData;

    public void setMobileDeviceData(MobileDeviceData mobileDeviceData) {
        this.mobileDeviceData = mobileDeviceData;
    }
}
```

And my MobileDeviceData class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class MobileDeviceData implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    private long deviceInfoId;

    @JsonProperty("resilient_id")
    private String resilientId;

    public long getResilientId() {
        return resilientId;
    }

    public void setResilientId(long resilientId) {
       this.resilientId = resilientId;
    }
}
```

The JSON coming in:

```
[
    {
        "reasonCode": "CHARGEBACK",
        "activityDate": 1447952509,
        "inPermId": "CUSTOMER InPermId",
        "transaction": {
            "mobile-data": {
                "resilient_id": 123
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Is there someway I can get it to load the `MobileDeviceData` object without having to create a `Transaction` object that wouldn't hold anything except for the `MobileDeviceData` class? I'm hoping there is some way I can modify the `@JsonProperty` to inform it that the object is inside the `Transaction` object.

Also, modifying the JSON is not an option. I already asked.

Comment: In the DeviceInfo, are you ommiting the transactino object ?

Comment: @reos - Yes, It would do nothing except hold the MobileDeviceData Object. So would like to omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json) SO thread and see both answers. I'm suggesting the second one. It will fit into your needs but it is a too custom solution - creating your own annotation and implementation despite of this, the code will look very clean, without dummy wrapper objects. I think is a very good and elegant solution.