# How to skip wrapper object in jackson json deserialization

Tags: android, json, jackson, pojo, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to deserialize the following string using the jackson.

```
{
  "roomName": "u8ec29p0j7q2m9f",
  "broadcastPresenceRoles": {
    "broadcastPresenceRole": [
      "moderator",
      "participant",
      "visitor"
    ]
  },
  "owners": {
    "owner": "anewuser@shahanshah"
  },
  "admins": {
    "admin": "sanjeet@shahanshah"
  },
  "members": null,
  "outcasts": {
    "outcast": [
      "sawan@shahanshah",
      "sus@shahanshah"
    ]
  },
  "ownerGroups": {
    "ownerGroup": "Friends"
  }
}
```

This the response from the openfire rest apis.
I am having problem with the wrapper object wrapping the arrays.
Here

```
"broadcastPresenceRoles": {
    "broadcastPresenceRole": [
      "moderator",
      "participant",
      "visitor"
    ]
  },
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312719/2450410) to unwrap the container but not getting success. I don't think writing wrapper classes is good idea (Since I will have to write several wrapper classes).Also I need the generalized solution so i can use it with other responses since the apis is having other responses in the similar wrapped objects format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does @JsonUnwrapped help?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom annotation with `@JsonDeserialize` inside and create a custom `JsonDeserializer` that implements `ContextualDeserializer`. The idea is inspired from [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json/17312719#17312719) you mentioned but it is more general to unwrap any one property in a json object.

Following is the custom annotation using `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` as annotation container contains `@JsonDeserialize`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer.class)
public @interface JsonUnwrapProperty {
}
```

and the custom `JsonDeserializer` that implements `ContextualDeserializer`:

```
public class JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private JavaType unwrappedJavaType;
    private String unwrappedProperty;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext deserializationContext, final BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        unwrappedProperty = beanProperty.getMember().getName();
        unwrappedJavaType = beanProperty.getType();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        final TreeNode targetObjectNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree().get(unwrappedProperty);
        return jsonParser.getCodec().readValue(targetObjectNode.traverse(), unwrappedJavaType);
    }
}
```

and the usage example:

```
public class MyBean {

    @JsonProperty("broadcastPresenceRoles")
    @JsonUnwrapProperty
    private List<String> broadcastPresenceRole;

    @JsonProperty("admins")
    @JsonUnwrapProperty
    private String admin;

    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

`@JsonProperty` is to locate the wrapper object and `@JsonUnwrappProperty` is to deserialize the json object and extract a property into the annotated field.

**Edited:**

Following is an example with `ObjectMapper`:

```
String json = "{\n" +
        "  \"broadcastPresenceRoles\": {\n" +
        "    \"broadcastPresenceRole\": [\n" +
        "      \"moderator\",\n" +
        "      \"participant\",\n" +
        "      \"visitor\"\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  \"admins\": {\n" +
        "    \"admin\": \"sanjeet@shahanshah\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}";

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final MyBean myBean = mapper.readValue(json, MyBean.class);

System.out.println(myBean.getBroadcastPresenceRole());
System.out.println(myBean.getAdmin());
```

Output:

> [moderator, participant, visitor]
>
> sanjeet@shahanshah

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and I am getting following exception-
    W/System.err: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.sked.jacksonparsingexample.entity.MyBean["broadcastPresenceRoles"])

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 23:43:13.920 24840-24840/com.sked.jacksonparsingexample W/System.err:     at com.sked.jacksonparsingexample.util.JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer.deserialize(JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer.java:33)

Comment: I have directly copied the classes you have given and I have tried with the json string with two properties only.

Comment: Also I have already tried the link you have given, Getting the same exception,@Wilson

Comment: I added an example for your reference. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I created a variation that solved the NPE based on @wilson response

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotationsInside;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonUnwrapProperty.JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer.class)
public @interface JsonUnwrapProperty {

  public static class JsonUnwrapPropertyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object>
      implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private JavaType unwrappedJavaType;
    private String unwrappedProperty;

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext deserializationContext,
        final BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
      unwrappedProperty = beanProperty.getMember().getName();
      unwrappedJavaType = beanProperty.getType();
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        throws IOException {
      System.out.println(String.format("Ignoring %s in %s/%s", unwrappedProperty,
        jsonParser.currentName(), jsonParser.nextFieldName()));
      JsonToken token = jsonParser.nextValue();
      return jsonParser.getCodec().readValue(jsonParser, unwrappedJavaType);
    }
  }
}
```