# Deserialize nested object into a single class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json such as:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "profile": { 
    "name": "Joe"
  } 
}
```

That I would like to deserialize as that:

```
class User {
  long id;
  String name;
}
```

Is there any simple way to annotate the class members to directly deserialize it without having to create an inner class?

Comment: No you can't. "profile" is an object type which having further attributes.

Comment: You can have a look to [my answer in other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38680610/6511967) and see whether it can help.

Comment: Seems that you're looking for a kind of reverse `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation, and that you're not the only one : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/42 and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/512 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip wrapper object in jackson json deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679451/how-to-skip-wrapper-object-in-jackson-json-deserialization)