# How to make POJO dynamic so that it ignores an json tag but reads the value under that tag using jackson in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, unmarshalling

I've a parent DAO:

```
 @XmlRootElement//(name="metadata") 
    public class FolderAttributes { 
    private Map nameValueForListValue;
```

Child DAO:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
    public class ListWrapper { 
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "attrValue")
    private List<Object> list;
```

JSON request that works (if I use "metadata" name as root element):

```
"metadata": {
    "nameValueForListValue": {
      "signed": {
        "attrValue": [
          "ahsdfhgakjf"
        ]
      },
"id": {
        "attrValue": [
          "12345678",
          "87654321"
        ]
      },
.......... continues
```

I don't want the tag "nameValueForListValue" in request, instead it should be smart enough to read rest of the values without that tag. Looks like it always needs to have the param name "nameValueForListValue" on the request. Is there any annotations that will do my job easier? I'm using Java 6 & jackson 1.9.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use code blocks next time to add readability to your question.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40686368/13075. I think it's regarding the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

What about using @JsonAnySetter Jackson annotation

It would be something like:

```
@XmlRootElement//(name="metadata")
public class FolderAttributes {
    private Map nameValueForListValue;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void genericSetter(String key, Object value){
        nameValueForListValue.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

That whay any unknown field could be handle by this setter.

More info:[@JsonAnySetter example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter)

Answer (score 0):

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)