# Jackson ObjectMapper returning null

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "customer")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data{
    @JsonProperty("salutation")
    public String salutation;
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("birthDate")
    public String birthDate;
}
```

I want to transform an incoming JSON to this POJO. Json look like this:

```
{   "customer": {
    "lastName": "test lastname",
    "firstName": "test firstname",
    "salutation": "test salutation",
    "birthDate": "test date",
    "addresses": {
      "city": "test city",
      "postalCode": "test postal code",
      "country": "test country",
      "streetNumber": "test number",
      "street": "test street"
    } } }
```

Problem: The actual data is not in the root tag, but nested in `"customer"`. This is why i used `@JsonRootName`. Also there is some data like city, postalCode, all in addresses, that I do not need for this object instance. Which is why i added `JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

When I use:

```
return mapper.readValue(getResource("/test.json"), Data.class);
```

It returns me an instance of Data, but null on every attribute of it. How can I fix this and why doesn't it work? First time using the jackson mapper here.. Thanks!

Comment: `public class Holder { public Data customer; }` followed by `mapper.readValue(source, Holder.class);`. Additionally drop all the annotations from the java class: it will work nicely without and why would you want to bind your class to a specific de/serialization method? If you need any special JSON de/serialization behaviour, bind it to the mapper, not the business object...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json