# How can I deserialize it using Java?

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have a  postgresql  function that returns json:

```
{
  "query_name": "information1",
  "query_type": "information2",
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "Test01",
      "age": "35",
      "isUpdate": false
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I deserialize it using Java?

My POJO

```
@Getter
@Setter 
class Information {
String name;
String type;
List<User> details; 
}

@Getter
@Setter 
class User {
String name; 
Integer age;
Boolean isUpdate; 
}
```

I want to use ObjectMapper but I can't do this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson - How to process (deserialize) nested JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747370/jackson-how-to-process-deserialize-nested-json)

Comment: @Deepanshu Rathi There is another json

Comment: @Deepanshu Rathi And how does it help me????  It is by default

Comment: I want to get this object (Information)  and work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Information` class to the following (mind the Jackson annotations to match JSON properties):

```java
@Getter
@Setter 
class Information {
    @JsonProperty("query_name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("query_type")
    String type;
    List<User> details; 
}
```

And then you just need to use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to convert your JSON String to the corresponding objects as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String informationJsonFromDatabase = ""; // whatever logic you need here to get the String from the database
Information information = 
        objectMapper.readValue(informationJsonFromDatabase, Information.class);
```

I have doubts regarding `Integer age;`, because in your JSON it is represented as a String, so I am not entirely sure that Jackson is able to do the convertion. If it is not you will need to either change the property to `String age;` or create a custom deserializer for `User` class.

Comment: I did this. It didn't work for me (

Comment: How to map details?

Comment: Did you get an exception? what didn't work? Without more information we can't help you. Can you add your tries to the question?

Comment: You don't need to map details, Jackson will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ...

```
class Information {
  String queryName
  String queryType
  List<User> details
}
```

Does it work for you ? Leave me a comment

Comment: I want to deserialize my json like this Object, and then work with the object. What should I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of that structure and use ObjectMapper.readValue() method to deserialise it.

This can help: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-json-to-java-object

you can pass the json input in string format as well if it is not stored in a file explicitly.

Comment: I tried this, but my object inner. I have list. What should I do about it?

Comment: iterate through that list. 

I assume you are asking about the details field there.

ExpectClassType jsonObj = objMapper.readvalue(String jsonInput, ExpectClassType.class)

jsonObj.details.get(0) or you can do a loop over that details field 

let me know if this helps

Comment: Is there really no better way to do this?

Comment: I guess, if your class structure is like,

class Information {
  String queryName
  String queryType
  List<User> details
}

and class User is your inner class, then it directly deserialize it if the structure matches, It is the easiest way I can think of using object mapper

Comment: I must have a nested iterate. Extract fields from Information and then in a second loop extract fields from User?

Comment: In the above sample output Information is not a list, then it is just informationObj.getDetails() which returns a list to loop through.

Otherwise it is a nested loop. one for Information then the Details

Comment: @ Pallavi Karjol   https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919098/10360597