# How to map JSON object with java Pojo class ignoring parent class spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I want to map below Json object with Java Pojo class ignoring parent class AuthToken.

```
{
  "AuthToken" : 
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "token" : "abcde1234xyz",
    "extendSession" : null
  } 
}
```

Pojo Class

```
public class TokenAccessResponseDTO {

    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would say use the JsonIgnoreProperties annotation and ignoreUnknown=true, then readValue() into a HashMap of <String, TokenAccessResponseDTO>

Comment: Though if you rather have a method to unpack the nested object directly without reading into hashmap, you could do so. Reference material [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize it using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917981/how-can-i-deserialize-it-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by mapping JSON Object to JsonNode and then adding the below syntax to fetch token

`jsonNode.findValue("token").asText()`