# Jackson with Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux

Json:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 3,
        "items": [
            6651536,
            20410167,
            40345521
        ]
    }
}
```

NOT WORK - `FriendsDTO`:

```
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class FriendsDTO {

    int count;

    @JsonProperty("items")
    List<Integer> friends;

}
```

WORK - `FriendsDTO`:

```
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class FriendsDTO {

    Response response;
    
    @Jacksonized
    @Builder
    @Value
    public static class Response {

        int count;

        @JsonProperty("items")
        List<Integer> friends;

    }

}
```

`WebFluxClient` request:

```
FriendsDTO friends = webFluxClient.get()
     .uri(config.methodGetFriends(), builder -> {
           builder.queryParam("access_token", accessToken);
           builder.queryParam("v", config.version());
           return builder.build();
      })
     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(FriendsDTO.class)
     .log()
     .block();
logger.info(friends.toString());
```

output WORK: `FriendsDTO(response=FriendsDTO.Response(count=3, friends=[6651536, 20410167, 40345521]))`

output NOT WORK: `FriendsDTO(count=0, friends=null)`

How can I get rid of this misunderstanding in the Response view for successful json parsing ?

Comment: Can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312719/5785871?

Comment: The question miss clarity. What do you want to achieve ? Do you want to inline the "response" container from the java binding ?

Answer (score 1):

Thats the expected behaviour

```
{
  name  : "name",
 description : "description"
}
```

This can be written as

```
class <ClassName>{
 private String name;
 private String description;
}
```

The json does not carry the `ClassName`. Similarly in your case, the word `Response` should be a valid attribute, like how I defined `name` in this example.

So , if you want , this class to work

```
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class FriendsDTO {

    int count;

    @JsonProperty("items")
    List<Integer> friends;

}
```

You JSON should be changed from

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 3,
        "items": [
            6651536,
            20410167,
            40345521
        ]
    }
}
```

To

```
  {
            "count": 3,
            "items": [
                6651536,
                20410167,
                40345521
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Of course, I immediately understood this, but I request this JSON from a third-party service.